# Using Docker to load Memory Image?

Tags: docker

As far as I understand Docker it is virtualizing a system and loads a certain image along with booting it and doing some other stuff. Since I can use different OS with docker, I think it is quite far reaching in order to provide such an abstraction.

In order to speed up setting up a test environment, is it possible to freeze a docker instance in a certain state (like after initializing the database) and rerun the image from this point?

Comment: I find it helps to think about a Docker container as an *isolated workspace* within the Linux host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is not virtualizing a system and boots it. Instead of loading its own system kernel into memory it simply creates encapsulated processes that run in the Linux kernel of the host system. That is by the way the reason why a Linux host is required.

There is no virtualization but just process/resource encapsulation. More details about the Docker architecture and its concepts you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#what-happens-when-you-run-a-container).

A "freeze" would be a [commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) of your base image which you used to [run](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) your container. You can get back to that commit at any point in time by using the image id.

Comment: But the freeze is just based on the file system so the next time I run the application inside the docker image, these file system state will be the base of it run. So I can for example start a database in a certain state but may not freeze the container and resume it anytime so it must go through the whole three seconds for starting the database.

Comment: Docker has no concept of storing running process states. When a container is started its process is always newly created.

Comment: Yeah. But imagen it would be the other way around :-)